# Is it possible to write a Windows service entirely in node.js?

Tags: windows, node.js, winapi, windows-services

I'm experimenting with using node.js beyond the server as a general-purpose scripting and application programming language.

One project on my TODO list would be a Windows service so I'm considering tackling it with node.js

I believe I have seen some kind of Windows API bindings for node.js but I don't know how complete or mainstream they are. (I'm willing to contribute!)

**What would it take to implement a Windows service in node.js?** (Trivial example appreciated.)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this very easily using [Winser](http://jfromaniello.github.com/winser/).

Comment: Well that slipped through my Googling! Thanks (-:

Comment: You're welcome, I've not tried it myself, but it's based on `nssm` which has proven to be very useful in the past :)

Comment: Hmm this turns out to use a "service manager" that can run any application as a Windows service. I'm not sure this is the same thing as writing a service from scratch in node.js using the Windows API. I might rework my question. Still it helped clarify my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Try [node-windows](http://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows). It's similar to WinSer, but has more options.